alpine Warning: found "[x-sort]", but missing sort plugin
I am building a dynamic form filter using Filament, and need sort for drag and drop static elements to the form.
Now, I know alpine and livewire comes inbuilt with filament, but when i run
consele.log(Alpine)  on the blade getting error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Alpine is not defined
// import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
import { Livewire, Alpine } from '../../vendor/livewire/livewire/dist/livewire.esm';
import sort from '@alpinejs/sort'


Alpine.plugin(sort)


Livewire.start()

this is how my app.js looks like.

I think you didn't add @vite(['resources/js/app.js']) and  @livewireScriptConfig  in your layout footer.

how to add this, because there isn't any layout we are extending ?

like that  @vite('resources/js/app.js')
